# onload wait script to load finish in react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this block in react to inject script, I put it within useEffect, but the problem is the script is big, the onload function trigger when the script is appended, it doesn't check whether the script is finished loaded, so what I did is I have to use setTimeout which is ugly, any clue?

```
useEffect(() => {
   function loadScript() {
     const script = window.document.createElement('script');
     script.src = `//my_external_script.js`;
     script.async = true;
     script.defer = true;
     script.onload = () => {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('do something all script is 
        finished loaded') ,2000)
     } 
   }
}, [])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem is the script is not small"?

Comment: @a-ctor meaning it's huge?

Comment: Not sure of the answer to your question, but I notice you've set both "async" and "defer". These are mutually exclusive, and you should pick only one. "async" means the script can start running while the rest of the page is still loading. "defer" means don't start running the script until the page is loaded.